# How do I make a list with a specified limit and let it be overwritten continuously?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I understand how to make a list but I'm not sure how to limit the list to a set amount or a good way to overwrite the list.

How would I do this? Also would an array be better perhaps?

Comment: Are you trying to build a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "overwrite the list?"

Comment: @ScottHannen I'm making an application whose job is to generate a list of 10 or so items and then every second a new value will be generated that will overwrite the oldest value.

Comment: How are you generating new values? After you populate it every second how are you then using this list?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic `Queue<T>`. (`Systems.Collections.Generic.`)

Create it as a private member in whatever class will manage it.

```
public class FixedSizeQueue<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();
    private readonly int _maxLength;

    public FixedSizeQueue(int maxLength)
    {
        _maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public void AddItem(T item)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
        while(_queue.Count > _maxLength)
        {
            _queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Items()
    {
        return _queue.ToArray();
    }
}
```

To clarify - `Enqueue` is like `Add` - it adds an item to the collection. `Dequeue` removes the oldest item in the collection. It returns that item since usually you're retrieving the oldest item in the list to do something with it.

This is just discarding the extra items. It doesn't include the part where you access what's in the queue because I'm not sure what you want to do with the items. But this is the basic code that will create a collection and ensure that it a) stays within the specified size and b) ejects the oldest items.

I added a method to copy a snapshot of what's in the queue to an array. That's the simplest way to access what's in the queue.

Comment: From the comments it appears that the intent is to always add the item, but to limit the size of the list by ejecting older items.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want string list capacity, not more than 10 then you can limit this way

```
        private List<string> _list = new List<string>();

        public void SetData(string value)
        {
            if (this._list.Count() < 10)
            {
                this._list.Add(value);
            }
        }

        public List<string> GetList()
        {
            return this._list;
        }
```

Comment: That won't replace older items with newer ones. As soon as the list reaches its capacity it will just discard newer items.

Comment: is OP want to overwrite or limit the list ? if he can limit the list then he can also overwrite the list because he knows the exact size